# How does the sklearn.preprocessing.scale works?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have an array of 2-dimensional data. describing the **income** of a person and his **age**
The data is being scaled before the model is prepared.  After the data is scaled it completely changes the value of the previous data to some new (near to 0 ) values.

````
from numpy import random, array

#Create fake income/age clusters for N people in k clusters
def createClusteredData(N, k):
    random.seed(10)
    pointsPerCluster = float(N)/k
    X = []
    for i in range (k):
        incomeCentroid = random.uniform(20000.0, 200000.0)
        ageCentroid = random.uniform(20.0, 70.0)
        for j in range(int(pointsPerCluster)):
            X.append([random.normal(incomeCentroid, 10000.0), random.normal(ageCentroid, 2.0)])
    X = array(X)
    return X



%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from numpy import random, float

data = createClusteredData(100, 5)

model = KMeans(n_clusters=5)

model = model.fit(scale(data))```


what does that scale actually do in that model? I came to know it brings data to the same level or at comparison state. But what Mathematical functions it performs in data. I have referenced the documentation of sci-kit learn but couldn't get what it means.  Please explain the operations performed in simple language
````

Answer (score 0):

It is removing the mean value from the data from each observation and then dividing by the standard deviation of the data

Check out the arguments for more details

```
with_mean boolean, True by default
   If True, center the data before scaling.

with_std boolean, True by default
   If True, scale the data to unit variance (or equivalently, unit standard deviation).
```

Comment: But does this way, all the diverse data come to comparable values?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, if you remove the mean from each observation, the mean of the resultant data is 0. Then if you divide each observation by the standard deviation, the resultant data has a standard deviation of 1. (so mean = 0 and sd = 1 for all variables). If this answers your question, consider marking this as the answer and/or upvoting so others can benefit from it when they refer to this in the future.

Comment: well , i don't have privilege to upvote , cause i dont have 15 points for reputation